# handling Museum tickets reservation

Tags: magento2, plugin

We need to manage and sell tickets' reservation for more museums.
Basically we need these features:

1) Reservation of tickets according to daily time-slot, showing availability for every time-slot (as example, one or more time-slots in one day could be inhibited because they result full).
Reservation has to be done with provision of a QR code.

2) Handling of reports towards every museum, where we need to clearly indicate how much museum earned, including commissions taken by us.

Could you indicate the most trustable plugin to be used to get these features?

Using Magento 2.0

Comment: Create your own custom plugin because there is no plugin available.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the option for paid plugins

https://store.webkul.com/Booking-And-Reservation-System-For-Magento2.html

https://bookingsystempro.com/

https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/booking-and-reservation

Lastly u have to do customization.

My suggestion choose the nearest, so need to do less customization.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Actually, second item seems to be more attractive for us...in any case, do you know if these magento extension's providers (for the second item, provider is magebay), are really trustable, especially concerning quality of their extensions and support they provide?

Comment: Where u can check the review & their support all i can say